# Google Cloud Natural Language API - Authorization

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-cloud-automl

I'm trying to usethe Cloud Natural Language API with the code given in this link. (first or second)
[link](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/analyzing-entities#language-entities-string-python)

I get the below error.

```
google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: 403 Your application has authenticated using end user credentials from the Google Cloud SDK or Google Cloud Shell which are nots
upported by the language.googleapis.com. We recommend configuring the billing/quota_project setting in gcloud or using a service account through the auth/impersonate_service
_account setting. For more information about service accounts and how to use them in your application, see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/.
```

I know that we need to give the json file of the service account key in the code as per google doc ([link](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#command-line)). But it does not say about handling the API Key. Also isn't it not recommended to give API Key in code. So what is the way?

I tried using the Curl command with the API Key and it works fine.

```
curl "https://language.googleapis.com/v1/documents:analyzeEntities?key=${API_KEY}" -s -X POST -H "Content-Type: applicat
ion/json" --data-binary @request.json
```

However i dont know how to incorporate the API Key (which i have) into the code present in the first link i posted above.

Comment: Are you using some SKD? Which language are you using?

Comment: @R.Esteves I'm using Python. I have opened a cloudshell editor from the same project which has the NLP API enabled.

Comment: Did you try puting `os.eviron['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = "/path/to/json/file" ` in the beginning of your code?

Answer (score 0):

Did you go through all the steps provided by [Google](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/setup)? You probably missed one of the steps outlined below.

- Create a project in GCP.
- Enable billing for that project.
- Enable the Natural Language API in that project.

  ```
    gcloud services enable language.googleapis.com --project [PROJECT_ID]
  ```
- Use your own account OR a service account key (with owner permissions).

  ```
    gcloud auth application-default login
  ```

  OR

  ```
    export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/home/user/Downloads/my-key.json"
  ```
- Set the project id trough the command line.

  ```
    gcloud config set project [PROJECT_ID]
  ```

Comment: I do not have the owner permission. The 'owner' had shared with me an API_KEY that has access to the Cloud NLP. So I'm trying to figure out how I would use this Key in that google doc's code (in the first link)

Comment: I used the curl command with the API_KEY and it worked. The issue with Curl is I'm not able to supply it as a csv. Neither able to supply multiple entries in that Json.

Comment: The API key is not needed if you correctly set up key file authentication. As outlined in the steps I posted above.